# Extract String from URL in Bigquery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have several 1.000 URLs and want to extract some values from the URL parameters. Here some examples from the DB:

`["//xxx.com/se/something?SE_{ifmobile:MB}{ifnotmobile:DT}_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H"]` 
`["//www.xxx.com/se/car?p_color_car=White?SE_{ifmobile:MB}{ifnotmobile:DT}_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H"]`

I want to extract the SE | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H

I have tried it with REGEXP_EXTRACT

`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Url,r'(?:\?|&)(?:([^_]+)_(?:[^&]*))') as Country`

The problem is since I have two '?' the outcome returns SE for the first url, and p for the second url. How can I solve this in one regexp so that I don't get the p but actual SE for the second url as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
[?&]([^_]+)_[^&?]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z1NwrI/1). Details:

- `[?&]` - a `?` or `&` char
- `([^_]+)` - Group 1 (the actual output string): one or more chars other than `_`
- `_` - a `_` char
- `[^&?]*` - zero or more `&` or `?` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Url, r'[?&]([^_]+)_[^&?]*$ as URL Was this the thought? I get error about unclosed string literal.

Comment: @user3052850 Sure, just close it, `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Url, r'[?&]([^_]+)_[^&?]*$')`